# Jquery slideToggle issue around <H3> tags

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I need small ammendment in the following jquery code. ([DEMO is here](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/U3zFR/1/))

If you notice in the demo, Heading One is sliding perfectly up/down as I want but Heading Two and Three are not. The difference is only I added another div around  ( "Heading Two" , "Heading Three" ) tag. I know, there needs to be done something with this line $(this).next("p").slideToggle("fast"); but I am not sure how to do that as I am begginer in Jquery.

Following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();

    $("h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").slideToggle("fast")
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    $('.mylink').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('p').prev().trigger('click');
    })
});
```

Please Guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not perfect, this will get you the functionality you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();

    $("h3").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.accordion').find("p").slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    $('.mylink').click(function(){
        $(this)
          .parent()
          .slideToggle('fast')
          .closest('.accordion')
          .find('h3')
          .toggleClass('active');
    })
});
```

Main changing being the use of `closest()` to locate the parent `.accordion` and use that as a point of reference to `find()` your `p` element.

Edit: codepen is borked for some reason, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LABpM/)

Comment: Great, Almost done! But small issue is left inside the para there is a close link. That link is not working now. Can you please help me in this too?

Comment: okay i've updated it to use the same method on the 'close' link

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Nick. Can you please share the updated code? I am not able to see latest on codepen.

Comment: Okay updated my answer (codepen seems to be borked, so i've switched back to jsfiddle).

Comment: Hey Nick, I just noticed in the fiddle that Arrows are not changing it's position from down to up when I press "Close" link inside the description whereas they are working fine when I click on headings. Can you please check what is the issue? I remember, in codepen version arrows were working fine.

Comment: I've edited the fiddle and the snippet to do what you need. At this point it might be better to just add and remove an 'active' class on your ``.accordian`` divs, that way you can just toggle that, rather than finding the ``p`` and ``h3`` elements. Just a thought ^^

Comment: Thanks for reply, Nick. But where did you update the code? I cannot see any updates on this URL http://jsfiddle.net/zN2jr/
"Close" link still not changing arrows position from up to down. Can you please give me update link? Thanks for your support. Really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Weird, code in fiddle was not updated. I've added a new fiddle link, but the code in my answer should still be working.

Comment: Perfect Now. You are Legend :)
Great Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is you are using a parent div on two and three headings, this works for exmple:

```
<h3 class="some_class">Heading One</h3>
```

but not this with your code

```
 <div class="some_class"><h3>Heading One</h3></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3zFR/4/)

Comment: You right, But I have no choice. I must use <div class="asp_panel"><h3>Heading One</h3></div>. Because this code needs to be incorporated in ASP.NET Panel. Any susggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Alright If you need to preserve the structure the .next() has to go. I couldn't figure out a less-messy way to do this, but combine the  and it's parent tag and look for sibling

:

```
$(this).parent().addBack().siblings("p").slideToggle("fast")
```

And as far as I can tell it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/damyanpetev/U3zFR/5/

Comment: Great, Almost done! But small issue is left inside the para there is a close link. That link is not working now. Can you please help me in this too?